# Connect router to VPN

Tags: wireless-networking, router, vpn, openvpn, draytek

I would like to connect my router to VPN in such a way, that would allow any house device to connect to router and be automatically routed through VPN.

This is quite different setup from usual dial-in connections I can find on the net.

I would like to be able to connect my router to VPN services like: https://www.slickvpn.com and allow any device to use VPN without additional software or configuration per device.

To give better example, I live in UK but I would like to have another router that would have US IP. That way any device connected to the "US" router would be able to access content only restricted to the US. All without a hassle of configuring VPN on each device separately.

My questions:

- Can this be done?
- I have DrayTek Vigor 2820Vn, and I can't seem to find the way to do above using this router. Looks like most VPN services are using MSCHAPv2 authentication and Vigor only has standard PAP one
- Which router would do the trick and where can I find some info how to set it up in that way?
- Can you recommend really reliable VPN services?

I hope above make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem SlickVPN only allow connections with OpenVPN clients, which as you know the DrayTek you have does not support for.

The 2820n (the 2820Vn, is the same model as the 2820n with VOIP support so for the purposes of setup guides etc on the VPN search for 2820n) supports `PPTP`, `IPSec`, `L2TP` and `L2TP over IPSec`.  So you have those options to choose from if you wish to use this router only.

There are plenty of services that can offer you this - choosing your own can only be left to you as recommendation for products are not regarded well here.

I put the following: `service vpn pptp OR ipsec OR l2tp` into my favourite search engine and it came up with what seemed good hits.  **Beware** though as you are providing a 3rd party with access to the traffic on your network.